# is ICC -check-pointers usable together with OpenMP critical sections?

Tags: c, openmp, icc

I would like to compile an MPI/OpenMP code together with the -check-pointers option of ICC. The code compiles fine in pure MPI (-fopenmp option omitted) or without the -check-pointers option. I couldn't find anything in the documentation of ICC about the two options being incompatible.

The cause for error seems to lie in named critical sections, I get lots of errors like the following when linking:

```
multiple definition of `.gomp_critical_user__nexport_'
```

Now, to my understanding, the whole idea of named critical sections is to define them multiple times with the same global name.

Comment: I'm surprised you have a gomp link error if you compile / link with Intel compiler. Are you sure you don't mix-up gcc and icc somewhere? Like using `mpicc` instead of `mpiicc` at some stage?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I couldn't find anything but mpiicc in the make process. The executable without check-pointers is linked to libiomp5.so

Comment: I just checked and indeed, icc's critical section names are of the form `.gomp_critical_user_XXX` with XXX the label given. However, I'm afraid that all the checking I can do since `icc: command line remark #10148: option '-check-pointers=rw' not supported` for me...